# Normalize database with thousand(s) of columns - design recommendations

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

Background: A lab I am assisting will be taking small saliva samples from mice. Each mouse will be assigned a patient number (Primary Key on the 1st table), and specific information pertaining to each mouse will be stored in this table (age, gender, etc.)

Each saliva sample will be assigned a unique number (Primary key, 2nd table), will reference the patient number, and be scanned 1000 times with their equipment. I am being tasked with recording and storing the values (doubles) for each saliva scan of each patient, each time the patient is sampled (multiple times per week).

We would theoretically like all the saliva sampling to be in a single table (I think). This would allow for population averages to be generated easily, and frequently updated. This would also assist in determining deltas between a given patient and the relevant population averages (similar age, gender, etc.).

My obvious concern is 1000+ columns is not a good practice in MySQL, or any database for that matter. I'm struggling to think of a good way to structure this data. (Perhaps each patient could have its own table of sample readings, but it would seem generating averages against the entire population would be problematic.)

**Edit**
I did not specify, but each scan has a specific wavelength of light being used, so each entry in the scans area should be referenced with its specific wavelength, in addition to a unique scan number.

Comment: I don't see 1000 columns in your description. I see 1000 rows.

Comment: Each sample is a row not a column.

Comment: Your last paragraph says "1000+ columns".  -- Do not do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your design is having the sample table contain the data for all of the scans, (1000+ of them).  That's where you are running into problems.

You need 3 tables.  One for patients, which you have described.  A second one for samples, and a third one for scans.

The scan table is where scan data would go.  This table would have maybe 4 columns  ScanId (a primary key).  SampleId (a foreign key to reference a row in the sample table), Sequence number, so you can put all the scans for a sample in chronological order (if necessary), and scan value.

The sample table now only has data values that occur once per sample, things like sample date.

You can join all three tables together when you need to.

Comment: Just so I am clear, in this scenario, every new scan instance would add ~1000 entries to this (the scans) table, with each entry referencing back to a Sample, and each sample references back to a patient (but in the samples table).


The scan table in this scenario is going to have somewhere in the hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of rows, but with decent indexing performance shouldn't take too bad of a hit, and I avoid an obscene number of rows.

Is this an accurate assessment of what you were describing?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/community) for this? Each mouse would have a document with the scan data.

You can then use MongoDB's onboard analytics (or use something like [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org)) to slice and dice your data at will.